# Parsing a csv file and calling rest api using python

Tags: python, rest

I am very new to Python ,I have a task to parse line by line a very huge .csv file and then based on comma separated values ,I have to call a REST api.Can some one help me with a sample code .

Based on the first column value from the csv file,I have to call different REST api or create different rest URL's and its corresponding parameters.What is the best way to have these stored ?Is it better to have a xml ,or hash map or ??? .so that when I read each line from csv ,i get the url and the required parameters from my config and then I have to make the URL for REST api and invoke the call.

Second question: Do we require any thread created so that it executes faster

My code is shown below.

```
import sys, argparse, csv, collections, time, datetime

EventAPIDict = {"evnet_1": "http://rest_apiurl/?",
                "evnet_2": "http://rest_apiurl/?"}

EventParamsDict = {"evnet_1": ("s", "ts"),
                "evnet_2": ("s")}

EventIndexDict = {"evnet_1": ("1", "4"),
                  "evnet_2": ("1")}

def processRow(row):
    print "-----------------------------"
    #print localRow
    event = row[0]
    if event in EventAPIDict:
        print event
        strRESTAPI = EventAPIDict[event]
        i = 0
        for param in EventParamsDict[event]:
            #print param
            indexes = EventIndexDict[event]
            value = row[int(indexes[i])]
            if param == "ts":
                timestamp = value #"2013-05-28 14:28:58"
                value = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime("%s")
            strRESTAPI = ("%s%s=%s&")%(strRESTAPI, param, value)
            i = i + 1

        strRESTAPI = strRESTAPI[:-1]
        print strRESTAPI
        #TODO: Invoke the Rest API

#TODO: Get the csv file to be parsed.
fileName = "LogDetails.log"
# open csv file
with open(fileName, 'rb') as csvfile:
    csvfile.seek(0)

    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        processRow(row)
```

Comment: how big is the `csv`?

Comment: Is it better to have a xml ,or hash map or ??? -- XML is a file format, while a hash map is a data structure in memory.  Maybe you could show us code that you have tried.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response.file size is around 16GB and proecssing should be really fast.

Comment: Please find my code ,but it takes a very long time to process

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question #1 -
yes, this script will parse a CSV file and act upon it. I used your basic structured to do the same thing in my script.  You can also parse it from XML or JSON formats as well, which are more portable to other systems.

I would have to see a data file to comprehend a bit more why your doing the comparisons and such. I would expect the input CSV contains all the information you need to call the REST API.

Second Question:

use [file seek](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm) function to create your different threads and execute a set number of calls.  of course, you also have the issue of how many calls can be made concurrently and how many can the server handle.